# Regular Expression to Search Quantity in Human Written Descriptions

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hello and thank you in advance,

I buy items that have a variety of human written listings on auction sites and forums.
Often times, the quantity is clear to a person, but extracting it has been a real challenge. I'm using google sheets and REGEXEXTRACT().

I consider myself to be a intermediate regex user, but this has me stumped, so I need an expert.

Here's a few examples, my desired return, and what I'm getting.

| Listing | Desired Return | Actual Return |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red 1996 Corvette 2x - Matchbox | 2 | 2 |
| 3 x SmartCar, broken 2nd door | 3 | 3 |
| 2nd edition Kindle (x3) | 3 | 3 |
| **1x** 2008 financial crash notice | 1 | 1 |
| Collectors Edition Beannie Baby, item 204/343 | 1 | **4** |
| (6) Nissan window motors (1995-1998 ONLY) | 6 | **N/A** |
| White chevy F150, 1996 | 1 | **6** |
| Green bowl, cracked (stored in room 2A5) | 1 | **5** |

As I thought through this, I think I can put some reasonable limitations on this logic, but the code is harder.

- The quantities will only be a single number 1-9. (perhaps reject all numbers > 9?)
- They'll possibly be precede by or followed by an X or x, with or without a space
- The quantity may be next to a special character like * , () or -
- It should ignore all 1st, 2nd, 3rd, - 9th style notation
- If a number is mixed in a word, like 2A3, it should ignore all

**Obviously most description don't have any quantity, so if there's no return or zero, that's fine.**

I have something that feels close, and does a reasonable job:

`[^a-wy-zA-WY-Z0-9]*([1-4]){1}([^a-wA-w0-9]|$)`

It doesn't return anything with the returns marked of **1***, and that's fine. It breaks on the last two, and I've struggled for too long!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `=IFNA(INT(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "\d{2,}|(x\d)|(\dx)|[^\W\d]+\d\w*|\d+[^\W\d]\w*", "$1$2"), "(\d)")), 1)`

Comment: Honestly, considering the vast array of unbounded/free-form data you’ll be working with, you may consider using an NLP model for this. There are just too many edge cases to boil down to a RegExp that can guarantee >80% effectiveness, IMO, but YMMV depending on how you might be able to clamp down on the upstream controls on input.

Comment: Wiktor.... nailed in! Wow. A+++

Comment: I made one small tweek, by making replacing A1 with LOWER(A1) to account for case differences. Thank you @WiktorStribiżew truly impressive!

Comment: If you're considering moving to a platform to something allowing for look-aheads/behinds this is maybe more readable: `((?<=(\-|\*|\(|X|x|\s))|^)\d((?=(\-|\*|\)|X|x|\s))|$)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
=IFNA(INT(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(LOWER(A27), "\d{2,}|(x\d)|(\dx)|[^\W\d]+\d\w*|\d+[^\W\d]\w*", "$1$2"), "(\d)")), 1)
```

Here,

- `REGEXREPLACE(LOWER(A27), "\d{2,}|(x\d)|(\dx)|[^\W\d]+\d\w*|\d+[^\W\d]\w*", "$1$2")` finds and *removes* chunks of two or more digits, or chunks with a digit and at least one letter, but keeps the sequences where a digit is preceded or followed with `x`
- `REGEXEXTRACT(..., "(\d)"))` extracts the first digit left after the replacement
- `=IFNA(INT(...), 1)` either casts the found digit to integer, or, if there was no match, inserts `1` into the column.

See the [long regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i8TL1J/1).

- `\d{2,}` - two or more digits
- `|` - or
- `(x\d)` - Group 1 (`$1`): `x` and a digit
- `|` - or
- `(\dx)` - Group 2 (`$2`): a digit and `x`
- `|` - or
- `[^\W\d]+\d\w*` - one or more word chars except digits, a digit and then zero or more word chars
- `|` - or
- `\d+[^\W\d]\w*` - one or more digits, a letter or underscore, and then zero or more word chars.

Demo:

[image]